# Интеграция Яндекс карт и 1С

Tags: yandex-maps-api, 1с

появилась необходимость привести к единому формату хранение адресов торговых точек.

Требуется следующий функционал:
На сайте, при создании торговой точки, клиент должен вбить адрес в поле поиска в яндекс картах, найти нужный дом и сохранить адрес. Обменом с 1С, создатся ТТ и сохранится корректный адрес.
Но, требуется аналогичный функционал в 1С, так как пользователи, забивают адреса, как хотят. Но нужен ответ от api в формате xml/yml для возможности парсинга.

Нашел метод https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation - по идее самое то, но не уверен, возможно есть более корректный метод.

Прошу помочь

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически можно попробовать использовать "HTTP-запрос на геокодирование", через http запрос закидываешь строку с адресом.
Помимо координат возвращает структурировано: дом, район, и т.д. + варианты которые походят.
но это все не в оперативном режиме

А вот если оперативно(т.е. корректировка данных на этапе ввода), то следует прикручивать пример из ссылки(что я бы делать не стал, но это возможно) думаю Вы не первый кто столкнулся с этой проблемой в 1с, я бы посмотрел в сторону адресных классификаторов

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы желаете не только помощи в выборе адреса пользователями (пример, что вы приводите), но и сохранение структурированного ответа в базу данных 1С, вам нужен **[Геокодер](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/)** с [расширенной коммерческой лицензией](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__tariff-plus).

Причём лучше применять их в паре - клиенты вводят адреса в строку с подсказкой, она обрабатывается (лучше, чем произвольный формат адреса) геокодером и сохраняется на вашей стороне.